# Batch escape colon :

Tags: batch-file, cmd, escaping

How can I echo a string that contains a colon :?

I know from http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php that most characters can be escaped using `^`, but that won't work for a colon **IF it is precededby `%0%`**

---

I have a batch file `x.bat` that contains

```
echo %0% http://blank
```

When run as `x.bat` it gives me:

```
x.bat//blank
```

I want it to print out

```
x.bat http://blank
```

---

How to do this?

Comment: Well done stripping the problem down to the least amount of code required to reproduce the failure.  It's nice not to have to read all day to figure out what's bugging someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a syntax problem. The filename of the batchfile is `%0`, not `%0%`:

```
echo %0 http://blank
```

Comment: Yes, `%0` expands to `x.bat`, and `% http:` is a failed expansion that becomes an empty string. The behavior is described at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7970912/1012053

Comment: The batch rules are a monstrosity. Thank you both; for spotting my error this fast, and for the helpful link.